# Is it possible to use a SKScene with a UIView Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sprite-kit, core-motion

I am using CoreMotion in my view to get the acceleration and rotation values in my phone. My app has multiple views that uses a view controller because I deal with data transfer, so I set up my view of the accelerometer/gyroscope with UIViewController. However I want to show a image of a ball that moves across the screen based on the values I get off the accelerometer and the gyroscope. I have been looking across at tutorials and that seems to be only done with games. Is there a way I can show a ball that uses CoreMotion to move without using SKScene?

Comment: You don't need SKScene. There are thousands of apps that use UIViewAnimation instead. Take a look at the guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: How do you propose to use SceneKit *without* a view controller?

Comment: @Caleb Sorry I don't follow, is that geared towards me?

Comment: @timedwalnut SpriteKit scenes are generally (always?) displayed in views, which are managed by view controllers. It might help to review [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21949952/643383).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a SKScene with a UIView Controller?

**Yes.** You're probably doing it already without realizing it.

The bridge between SpriteKit and Cocoa Touch's view architecture is `SKView`. A lot of SpriteKit-based apps just have one view controller whose view is a `SKView`, and then they handle different phases of the game by doing all their drawing in SpriteKit and just changing sprite scenes. But you don't have to work that way -- you can mix `SKView` with other views and controls, and you can use as many view controllers as you like.

Here's a shot of a `SKView` inside another view and managed by a view controller that's embedded in a  navigation controller:

[image: Hello, world!]

The purple area is a plain old `UIView` -- only the black area is a SpriteKit view.

> Is there a way I can show a ball that uses CoreMotion to move without using SKScene?

**Yes.** If all you want to do is to move a ball across the screen, the [UIKit animation built into `UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) is almost certainly more than enough.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 choices. Either try using UIView's built in animation controls, like in the following example:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 

    //Insert Animations Here
}
```

Alternatively, you could always create a view within the View Controller's main view and make that view an SKView and present an SKScene with it.

Something like the following:

```
sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 666, height: 500))
sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

if let view = self.sceneView as SKView? {
    // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }

    view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true


}
```

Replace the width and height with preferred values.

Comment: Would you know how to use the accelerometer values to move the ball continuously, instead of having it animate for only a certain duration?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the accelerometer but you might be able to use a selector for when the accelerometer detects an input. Alternatively, you could use a Timer objet to repeatedly check for input but a selector is probably your best bet.